# How to catch records that fail when trying to create in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating new records, and want to be able to catch the ones that error and add them to my activity log so I can look into them and why they may have failed.

What would be the best way to do this?

Currently, I am creating categories bu passing over an array of categories.

```
Category.create(categories)
```

I have validation on the name of the category to make sure its unique.

I would like to see which ones have failed and also have a total count of which ones were created vs failed. For example...

- xyz failed to be created.
- Created 99/100 categories, 1 failed.

I am using a simple activity log which I have made myself. And would like to have these details stored in the ***"log_msg"***

```
ActivityLog.create(:act_type => "Insert", :updated_by => "System", :activity => log_msg, :act_tstamp => Time.now)
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: [`::create!`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/create%21) will raise an error on failure so rescuing that should not be difficult

Comment: I did try that, but that fails the whole thing as I validate the name of the category being inserted. - Updated my post to say about the validation.

Comment: You would need to loop categories to keep track of the success and failure rate rather than passing an `Array` to `create!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust this code to your needs:

```
invalid_categories = []

categories.each do |category|
  begin
    Category.create!(category)
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => exception
    invalid_categories << category
  end
end

log_msg = invalid_categories.map { |category| "#{category} failed to be created" }
log_msg << "Created #{categories.size - invalid_categories.size}/#{categories.size}, #{invalid_categories.size} failed"
log_msg = log_msg.join("\n")

puts log_msg # log somehow the message
```

Also take a look at [this article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations) because of:

> Rails does many things, but data integrity validations are not one of
>   them. Your relational database is designed to enforce data integrity